# Create a file that's treated like a btrfs file system

Tags: filesystems, mount, btrfs, mkfs

I want to do a few experiments on the btrfs file system, but I don't want to make any changes to my existing partitions, and I want full control over things like device size.

Is it possible to create a file that *looks* like a block device that I can mount and unmount, and that will act like a block device such as running out of space?

Comment: @nwilder I don't think it's a duplicate, although it does seem quite close. It's like the two questions are asking similar things, but working from opposite starting points.

Comment: You might be looking for a "loop" device.

Comment: @roaima yup, creating is one thing, mounting is another, bot to reopen

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The loop device is what you need for this. Run these commands as root:

```
truncate -s1G 1GB.img  # Sparse allocation of a 1GB file
ld=$(losetup --show --find 1GB.img); echo "$ld"
```

You will now have a loop device (for example, `/dev/loop0`) that you can treat as a block device.

```
mkfs -t btrfs "$ld"    # Device that was returned from losetup

mkdir -p /mnt/dsk
mount "$ld" /mnt/dsk
```

When you've finished, tidy up again

```
umount /mnt/dsk
losetup -d "$ld"
rm 1GB.img
```

If you want to create a partition table on the block device, make sure you always include the `--partscan` flag on the `losetup` command. This will create the associated devices, for example, `/dev/loop0p1`.

Comment: These days, you can even do the `mount file.img /mnt/point` and `mount` will create the loop device by itself.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas ah yes, `truncate` is a much better option for a filesystem image, thank you. (For throwaway scripts I too often forget about `truncate`.) Re `mount`, the question asked for a block device, so I offered the result from `losetup`.